# What role does $1/\alpha$ play in the last integral?

Tags: logarithms

> If we examine the inverse function $f^{-1}=log_{10}$, the whole situation appears in a new light:
>
> $$\begin{align}
> log_{10}'(x)&=\frac1{f'\left(f^{-1}(x)\right)}\\
> &=\frac1{\alpha\cdot f\left(f^{-1}(x)\right)}=\frac1{\alpha x}
> \end{align}$$
>
> The derivative of $f^{-1}$ is about as simple as one could ask! And, what is even more interesting, of all the integrals $\displaystyle\int_a^bx^n\,\mathrm dx$ examined previously, the integral $\displaystyle\int_a^bx^{-1}\,\mathrm dx$ is the only one which we cannot evaluate. Since $\log_{10}1=0$ we should have $$\frac1\alpha\int_1^x\frac1t\,\mathrm dt=\log_{10}x-\log_{10}1=\log_{10}x$$

$\alpha$ is defined as follows:

> …then ($*$) will imply that $f(x)=10^x$ for rational $x$, and $10^x$ could be *defined* as $f(x)$ for other $x$; in general $f(x)$ will equal $[f(1)]^x$ for rational $x$.
>
> One way to find such a function is suggested if we try to solve an apparently more difficult problem: find a *differentiable* function $f$ such that
>
> $$f(x+y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)\quad\text{for all }x\text{ and }y\text,\\f(1)=10$$
>
> Assuming that such a function exists, we can try to find $f'$—knowing the derivative of $f$ might provide a clue to the definition of $f$ itself. Now
>
> $$\begin{align}
> f'(x)&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h\\
> &=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)\cdot f(h)-f(x)}h\\
> &=f(x)\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-1}h\\
> \end{align}$$
>
> The answer thus depends on $$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-1}h\text;$$ for the moment assume this limit exists, and denote it by $\alpha$. Then $$f'(x)=\alpha\cdot f(x)\quad\text{for all }x$$
>
> Even if $\alpha$ could be computed, this approach seems self-defeating. The derivative of $f$ has been expressed in terms of $f$ again.

Why is it here? I can't make any sense out of its use.

Answer (score 0):

Just above it is argued that
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\log_{10}(x)=\frac{1}{\alpha x},\quad x>0,
$$
with $\alpha=\log(10)$. In other words, an anti-derivative of $x\mapsto \frac{1}{\alpha x}$ is $\log_{10}$. That is why
$$
\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\,\mathrm dt=\int_1^x\frac{1}{\alpha t}\,\mathrm dt=\log_{10}(x)-\log_{10}(1)
$$
as a consequence of [the fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Corollary).